# $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ $f(x,y)=(x^2+y^2,x^2-y^2)$. How could I find the inverse of $f,$ should it exist?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm largely struggling to conceptualise this problem and how I might show it's invertible. From what I can gather, this function describes a slice of a 3D elliptic and hyperbolic paraboloid. Beyond this, I'm stumped.

Comment: $f(x,y)=f(-x,-y)$ so inverse does not exist.

Comment: For an inverse function to exist, each output would need to be mapped to by only one input: consider what happens when we flip the signs of $x$ or $y.$ (we can fix this issue by limiting the range of our inverse to nonnegative $x$ and $y$, in which case this just involves solving the system $x^2 + y^2 = a, x^2 - y^2 = b$ for $x$ and $y,$ so you find the inputs which map to any given output)

Comment: I thought all this originally, but I've been staring at the problem so long that I forgot what to even look for.. so thank you for easing my mind!

Comment: Another approach is just to let $f(x,y) = (u,v)$ and try to solve for $x, y$. In this case setting $f(x, y) = (u,v)$ gives two equations $$x^2 + y^2 =u\\x^2-y^2 = v$$ from which it is easy to solve $x = \pm\sqrt{(u+v)/2}, y = \pm\sqrt{(u-v)/2}$. Because of the $\pm$, we see that every valid output of $f$ is given by four inputs, so the solution is not unique, and the function is not invertible. But even if you restrict the domain $f$ to only non-negative coordinates, the function would still not be invertible, because there are points in the codomain of $f$ where the inverse does not exist.